# Display row number in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is the situation: I have a Transaction model that is supposed to register some financial transactions and I want to know the actual number of the transaction. Initially I used the primary key but I wanted to have a separate field to keep track of this because, if a row is deleted, I want the number of the line to be decremented. For instance, if I have 10 rows, I add the number 11, I delete it and when I add a new line, it will be number 11 (and not 12 with the primary key). I realize that this solution is fine only if the last row is deleted.

What I did was to create a model (`Meta_Stuff`) to store the actual transaction number. Then I created methods to decrements and increments the transaction number when a transaction is deleted or created.

Here is the code:

```
class Meta_Stuff(models.Model):
    # only one instance
    transac_number = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.transac_number

    @classmethod
    def get_lastnumber(cls, default=1):
        return cls.objects.get(pk=1).transac_number
        # number = get_object_or_404(cls, pk=default)
        # return number.transac_number

    @classmethod
    def increment_lastnumber(cls):
        new = cls.objects.get(pk=1)
        new.transac_number += 1
        new.save()

    @classmethod
    def decrement_lastnumber(cls):
        new = cls.objects.get(pk=1)
        if new.transac_number >1:
            new.transac_number -= 1
            new.save()


class Transaction(models.Model):
    numero = models.IntegerField(default=Meta_Stuff.get_lastnumber)
    # numero = models.IntegerField(default=Meta_Stuff.objects.first().transac_number)
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    somme = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    compte = models.ForeignKey(Compte, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    budget = models.ForeignKey(Budget, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    date_traitement = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    description = models.TextField()

    facture = models.FileField(upload_to=facture_path, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom

    def facture_name(self):
        return self.facture.name.split('/')[-1]





@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=Transaction)
def execute_after_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        ## transac number
        Meta_Stuff.increment_lastnumber()

        ## current Compte/budget
        c = Compte.objects.get(nom=instance.compte)
        c.somme_actuelle += instance.somme  # change field
        c.save()  # this will update only
        if  instance.budget:
            b = Budget.objects.get(nom=instance.budget)
            b.somme_actuelle += instance.somme  # change field
            b.save()  # this will update only

@receiver(models.signals.pre_delete, sender=Transaction)
def execute_before_delete(sender, instance, using, *args, **kwargs):
    ## transac number
    Meta_Stuff.decrement_lastnumber()

    ## current Compte/budget
    c = Compte.objects.get(nom=instance.compte)
    c.somme_actuelle -= instance.somme  # change field
    c.save()  # this will update only
    if instance.budget:
        b = Budget.objects.get(nom=instance.budget)
        b.somme_actuelle -= instance.somme  # change field
        b.save()  # this will update only
```

It worked when the database was sqlite but I then decided to move to PostgreSQL. Then, I had this error:

```
>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, compta, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying compta.0011_auto_20180119_1119...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\compta\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\compta\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 356, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\compta\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\compta\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\compta\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 204, in handle
fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\compta\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 115, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\compta\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\compta\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\compta\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 129, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\compta\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 216, in database_forwards
schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\compta\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 515, in alter_field
old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\compta\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\schema.py", line 112, in _alter_field
new_db_params, strict,
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\compta\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 613, in _alter_field
new_default = self.effective_default(new_field)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\compta\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 207, in effective_default
default = field.get_default()
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\compta\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 782, in get_default
return self._get_default()
  File "D:\Projets\aesc_compta\compta\models.py", line 44, in get_lastnumber
return cls.objects.get(pk=1).transac_number
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\compta\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\compta\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 380, in get
self.model._meta.object_name
compta.models.DoesNotExist: Meta_Stuff matching query does not exist.
```

As I understand, when I try to migrate the databases, it tries to get the  instance of `Meta_Stuff` with `pk=1` but throw an error because it does not exist. This is normal because there is nothing in the databases yet.

Honestly I'm a little bit lost with this.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you could do.

You could change the methods in `Meta_Stuff` to use `get_or_create` instead of `get`.

You could create an instance in your migration just after creating the model, before creating the `Transaction` model.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution!

I just needed to add initial data with
`python manage.py loaddata <initial data file>`

Initially, I thought that I would need to `migrate` before loading the initial data but apparently not. It may come from the fact that I already had some migrations (done with the sqlite database).